# Magento 2.2.2 - RequireJS domReady! not working with Slick Product Slider

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs, slider

**Issue**

> Slick slider breaking/not loading properly on page load and eventually
>   breaking the product slider

**Solution:**

> Load slick slider script after entire document is loaded and parsed

**domReady! vs domReady**

> - If you include it in the the requirements array w/a trailing `!` your    module won't execute until it's "safe" to interact w/ the DOM.
> - If you omit the `!`, then it's just a normal module that happens to    be a function, which can take a callback that won't execute before
>     the DOM is safe to interact with.

Reference - http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload

**Using below script for domReady!**

```
slider: function () {
    require([
        'jquery',
        'domReady!',
        'slider'
    ], function ($, slider) {

        slider({"class": "slick-slider-recently-viewed", "number": 4, "tablet": 3, "landscape": 2, "portrait": 1});
        slider({"class": "slick-slider-recommended", "number": 4, "tablet": 3, "landscape": 2, "portrait": 1});

    });
}
```

Exception - `Uncaught TypeError: slider is not a function`

Tried below using `domReady` and it is working

```
slider: function () {
    require([
        'jquery',
        'domReady',
        'slider'
    ], function ($, domReady, slider) {

        domReady(function () {

        slider({"class": "slick-slider-recently-viewed", "number": 4, "tablet": 3, "landscape": 2, "portrait": 1});
        slider({"class": "slick-slider-recommended", "number": 4, "tablet": 3, "landscape": 2, "portrait": 1});

        });
    });
}
```

How do I use `domReady!` instead of `domReady` ? What I understand is domReady is not a method but a RequireJS module.

Do I have to use in `define` instead of `require` like below as used in \vendor\magento\module-admin-notification\view\adminhtml\web\toolbar_entry.js

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "jquery/ui",
    "domReady!"
], function ($) {
    'use strict';
```